# How use implementation with private constructor in DryIoc?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, dryioc

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass {
    internal MyClass() {
    }
}

container.Resolve<IMyClass>();
```

How to configure DryIoc to use the constructor of `MyClass` in case when it is internal, protected or even private?

Comment: Why do you wish to have an internal constructor?

Answer (score 3):

Specify constructor info via Made.Of:

```
c.Register<Something>(made:
     Made.Of(typeof(Something).GetConstructorOrNull(includeNonPublic: true,  args: argTypes));
```

### Update:

Here is the custom implementation of constructor selector.

Couple of notes:

- Does not support `Func<..>`, but support can be easily added by copying from the `FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments` implementation
- Will be supported by DryIoc when [issue 313](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/issues/313/support-non-public-constructors-with) is resolved

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  namespace DryIoc.IssuesTests
  {
      [TestFixture]
      public class SO_question_How_use_implementation_with_private_constructor_in_DryIoc
      {
          public class A { internal A() { } }
          public class B { internal B(A a) { } }

          [Test]
          public void Test()
          {
              var c = new Container();
              c.RegisterMany(new[] {typeof(A), typeof(B)},
                  made: Made.Of(SelectMostResolvableConstructor(includeNonPublic: true)));

              c.Resolve<B>();
          }

          private FactoryMethodSelector SelectMostResolvableConstructor(bool includeNonPublic = false)
          {
              return request =>
              {
                  var implementationType = request.ImplementationType.ThrowIfNull();
                  var ctors = implementationType.GetAllConstructors(includeNonPublic: true).ToArrayOrSelf();
                  if (ctors.Length == 0)
                      return null; // Delegate handling of constructor absence to the Caller code.
                  if (ctors.Length == 1)
                      return FactoryMethod.Of(ctors[0]);

                  var ctorsWithMoreParamsFirst = ctors
                      .Select(c => new {Ctor = c, Params = c.GetParameters()})
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Params.Length);

                  var rules = request.Container.Rules;
                  var parameterSelector = rules.Parameters.And(request.Made.Parameters)(request);

                  var matchedCtor = ctorsWithMoreParamsFirst.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                          x.Params.All(p => IsResolvableParameter(p, parameterSelector, request)));

                  var ctor = matchedCtor.ThrowIfNull(Error.UnableToFindCtorWithAllResolvableArgs, request).Ctor;

                  return FactoryMethod.Of(ctor);
              };
          }

          private static bool IsResolvableParameter(ParameterInfo parameter,
              Func<ParameterInfo, ParameterServiceInfo> parameterSelector, Request request)
          {
              var parameterServiceInfo = parameterSelector(parameter) ?? ParameterServiceInfo.Of(parameter);
              var parameterRequest = request.Push(parameterServiceInfo.WithDetails(ServiceDetails.IfUnresolvedReturnDefault, request));

              if (parameterServiceInfo.Details.HasCustomValue)
              {
                  var customValue = parameterServiceInfo.Details.CustomValue;
                  return customValue == null
                      || customValue.GetType().IsAssignableTo(parameterRequest.ServiceType);
              }

              var parameterFactory = request.Container.ResolveFactory(parameterRequest);
              return parameterFactory != null && parameterFactory.GetExpressionOrDefault(parameterRequest) != null;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: OK, I hope it is possible to apply it to RegisterMany... And it is not clear where can I get argTypes in that case... it can be absolutely different..

Comment: Use GetSingleConstructorOrNull,  it does not require args, but assume you have a single ctor. If you need automatic constructor selection based on most resolvable version,  currenty it supports only public ctors: `new Container(rules => rules. With(FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments)` or per

Comment: registration `c.RegisterMany(..., made: FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments)`.  To en

Comment: To enable non public constructor selection,  you can write custom FactoryMethodSelector.  Copy code from `ConstructorWithResolvableArguments` and modify it for all constructors.  Bit tedious for now,  but I'll probably add support for this in v2.7